# Unable to print SOAP response parameter in CSV results file using Beanshell Postprocessor in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to create the script for WSDL soap services and my requirement is i want to print points response output parameter value into a csv results file using Beanshell Postporcessor.

Below is the response of SOAP.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <CardResponse xmlns="http://service.clp.eks.com">
         <out>
            <birthDate xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">05-04-00</birthDate>
            <cardno xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com"/>
            <customerName xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">krishna singhji</customerName>
            <flag xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">TRUE</flag>
            <memberLevel xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com"/>
            <points xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">**500.0**</points>
            <reason xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com"/>
         </out>
      </CardResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**My Beanshell Script is :**

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

CardNo =vars.get("cardno");

Result = "FAIL";
Response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

if(Response.contains("TRUE"))
    Result = "PASS";
Points = vars.get("points");

f = new FileOutputStream("F:\\Java_Applications\\apache-jmeter-3.1\\bin\\CardsResults.csv",true);
p=new PrintStream(f);

this.interpreter.setOut(p);

p.println(CardNo + "," + Points + "," + Result);
f.close();
```

After running the TestPlan my results file not displaying value for points and displaying as null value,Please help me how to resolve this issue.ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks more or less OK so the problem seems to be with the `${points}` JMeter Variable.

If you set it somewhere before your Beanshell script - double check this place where you define it and double check the expected value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) combination.

If you don't extract this `${points}` variable - you need to do this before the Beanshell PostProcessor i.e. using [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) configured like:

- Reference Name: `points`
- XPath query: `//points`

[image: XPath Extractor Configuration]

[image: XPath Tester Demo]

And make sure you put XPath Extractor **before** the Beanshell PostProcessor.

---

Going forward consider using [JSR223 PostProcessor and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) instead of Beanshell, it is more performing scripting option.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and if i'm using Xpath Extractor and Debug Sampler then in csv file two records are inserting for 1 iteration,if i'm running for 4 iterations then 8 records are inserting in CSV file.